# GKObstacleGraph<GKGraphNode2D> does not handle archiving

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, path-finding, gameplay-kit

I'm using GameplayKit's GKObstacleGraph to add path finding support to my iOS 10.2 SpriteKit game.
The game is a top-down 2D game, it features impassable obstacles which my 'soldiers' can't walk through.

Creating a GKObstacleGraph for my game level, with about 500 obstacles, takes ~50 seconds. This is too long for my users to wait.

Since the game map layout never changes dynamically after being loaded, I decided to create the graph once:

```
let graph = GKObstacleGraph(obstacles: obstacles, bufferRadius: 5, nodeClass: GKGraphNode2D.self)
```

Archive it to file:

```
let directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
if let documents = directories.first {
   if let filePath = String(documents + "/obstacle.graph") {
      NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(graph, toFile: filePath)
   }
}
```

Copy the file from device to my laptop and add the file to my bundle. Then I just unarchive the graph object when I load my game level:

```
if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "obstacle", ofType: "graph") {
        let graph = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: filePath) as! GKObstacleGraph<GKGraphNode2D>
        return graph
}
```

In theory, this should be much quicker since I don't have to calculate the graph, only read it(unarchive) from file.

However, depending on the number of obstacles and their relative placement one of three things happens:

1. NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject crashes.
2. Archive works but NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject crashes.
3. Both archive and unarchive works, but I can not find a path around obstacles with GKObstacleGraph.findPath

I can get all of this working if I skip the (un)archive steps:

[Successful path finding](https://s30.postimg.org/nejytreap/image.png)

Also, on simulator (iPhone 7), (un)archive **never crashes**, but path finding **always fails** afterwards.

What is going on here? I've reported it as a bug to Apple, but I'm still hoping that I've missed something.

I tried alternative solutions to the problem where I'm writing/reading nodes and obstacles to file using my own format. But the obstacle property of GKObstacleGraph is **get** only, which leaves me with the constructor, and then I'm back to waiting 50 seconds again.

I've created a public test project git repo:

https://bitbucket.org/oixx/gkobstaclegraphcrashproof.git

which shows the three different scenarios that fails when running on device. For simplicity it reads/writes the file to device, not bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the crashes, but #3 in your list is probably caused by `connectNodeToLowestCostNode:bidirectional:` not actually connecting your soldier to the graph because the nodes array is immutable after unarchiving.

The solution is to archive the nodes instead of the graph, then just create a graph from the nodes

```
NSArray *nodes  = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:self.nodesArray];
GKGraph *graph  = [[GKGraph alloc] initWithNodes:nodes];
```